# Find image inside a div and make that the divs background

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just wondering how to find the `<img>` inside a div and make that the div's background via css?

any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have tried.

```
var getImageSrc = $('#block-2 img').attr('src');

// add div background image using the variable above
$('#block-2').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');

    <div id="home-blocks">

    <div id="block-1"><?php the_block('Block 1')?></div>

    <div id="block-2"><?php the_block('Block 2')?></div>

    <div id="block-3"><?php the_block('Block 3')?></div>

    <div id="block-4"><?php the_block('Block 4')?></div>

    <div id="block-5"><?php the_block('Block 5')?></div>

    <div id="block-6"><?php the_block('Block 6')?></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You want to take the `img` tag from the `div` and make it the background of the div? there is only one `img` in every `div`?

Comment: Yes only one image inside the div.

Comment: updated question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').each(function(){

 if($(this).find('img').length > 0)
 {
  var imgSrc = $(this).find('img').prop('src');
  //$(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    $(this).css('background-image','url(' + imgSrc + ')');
 }
});
```

Comment: This does not make the image inside the div become the divs background image? :)

Comment: i thought u said detect divs that have image inside them and change the background to something of that divs

Comment: No sorry - use the <img> inside that div and set it to the background-image css for that div? :)

Comment: Still no luck - but that looks like it is right. :(